# In angular2 I have a pipe that is used in two components and would like to know how to share it globally

Tags: angular

In angular2 I have a pipe that is used in two components and would like to know how to share it globally

I'm using angular2 and typescript.

My filter is called filterJobs pipe.

Where is best to inject filterJobs pipe so that it's available to both components from a global location?

**This is my current attempt at making an ngModule for the filter to share it:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { JobsFilter } from './jobsFilter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [JobsFilter],
  exports: [JobsFilter],
  providers: []
})
export class JobsFilterModule { }
```

> Then do I simply inject "JobsFilterModule" into the component that
> needs it? If yes then does this go into the import section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a module `@NgModule()class MyPipeModule {}` where you put the pipe in `declarations: []` and `exports: []`, then add `MyPipeModule` to `imports: []` of very module where you want to use it.
This will make the pipe and other components, and directives added to `exports: []` available to all components in your current module.

Comment: I've added my code above at creating a module, can you check it looks correct?

Comment: Looks great. I don't know what you mean by "Then do I simply inject "JobsFilterModule" into the component that needs it?" You don't need to inject a pipe. Just add `imports: [JobsFilterModule]` to the `@NgModule()` where you want to use it.

Comment: I've imported the JobsFilterModule input the components module, do I next need to add it to the pipes array in the component.ts file?

Comment: No, just add it to imports. There shouldn't be anything else necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your components are in two different modules (e.g. M1, M2) you can declare your pipe in a shared module that both M1 and M2 import.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      FilterJobsPipe,
      ...
      ],
    ...
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

In your component modules you then would import the shared module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      SharedModule,
      ...
    ]
...
})
export class ModuleX {}
```